# Preserve aspect ratio for SVG Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

*This is an edited copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105120/preserve-aspect-ratio-for-svg-text-and-react-to-javascript-touch-events which I will remove, because it asked 2 related but technically different questions.*

as I already explained in my last question, I'm trying to make a navigation-div with 4 buttons, one to go left, one to go right, another one to go down and yet another one to go up. Plus there needs to be an OK-button in the middle.

That worked really well with the explanation given here: [Using CSS and HTML5 to create navigation buttons using trapezoids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835743/using-css-and-html5-to-create-navigation-buttons-using-trapezoids)

I created the SVG like:

```
<div class="function height3x svg-container" style="height: 112px; width: 200px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="background-color: whitesmoke">
    <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_24">
        <polygon id="ok" points="25,25 75,25 75,75 25,75"></polygon>
        <text id="ok_text" x="39" y="55">OK</text>
    </g>
    <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_25">
        <polygon id="up" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,0 100,0 65,35 35,35"></polygon>
        <text x="42" y="20"></text>
    </g>
    <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_26">
        <polygon id="right" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="100,0 100,100 65,65 65,35"></polygon>
        <text x="81" y="53"></text>
    </g>
    <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_27">
        <polygon id="down" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,100 35,65 65,65 100,100"></polygon>
        <text x="42" y="91"></text>
    </g>
    <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_28">
        <polygon id="left" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,0 35,35 35,65 0,100"></polygon>
        <text x="5" y="53"></text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

But I have two problems that I seem not to be able to figure out.

First of all: While I want the SVG to be responsive, I don't want to scale the text without keeping the aspect-ratio given by the font.

[image: Text that was scaled vs. non-scaled]

I already tried (unsuccessfully) preserveAspectRatio, which does not seem to do much to the text.

**Questions: How can you make the  tag keep it's aspect ratio, while changing the aspect ratio of the svg?**

You can view and edit the minimal example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noLhdqLq/)

Paulie_D - Commented on my old question:

> As for the Aspect Ratio, you should remove the width & height 100%
>   values. They aren't really needed. The SVG will scale to the required
>   size based on the div size. - jsfiddle.net/2qqrL7ng/1 –

This is not an option, because the SVG Element needs to respond to size changes that can not keep the aspect ratio. Just the text needs to keep the ratio, everything else should be as responsive as possible.

EDIT

Switching the svg argument of perserveAspectRatio from "none" to "xMidYMid" keeps the aspect ratio of the SVG, but the desired effect is, that the SVG itself does not keep it's aspect ratio, but the -tags do. Which means the following would **NOT** be a solution:

```
<div class="function height3x svg-container" style="height: 112px; width: 200px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="mySVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" style="background-color: whitesmoke">
        <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_24">
            <polygon id="ok" points="25,25 75,25 75,75 25,75"></polygon>
            <text id="ok_text" x="39" y="55">OK</text>
        </g>
        <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_25" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
            <polygon id="up" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,0 100,0 65,35 35,35"></polygon>
            <text x="42" y="20"></text>
        </g>
        <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_26">
            <polygon id="right" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="100,0 100,100 65,65 65,35"></polygon>
            <text x="81" y="53"></text>
        </g>
        <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_27">
            <polygon id="down" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,100 35,65 65,65 100,100"></polygon>
            <text x="42" y="91"></text>
        </g>
        <g class="function" id="keyboard_btn_28">
            <polygon id="left" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" points="0,0 35,35 35,65 0,100"></polygon>
            <text x="5" y="53"></text>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

/EDIT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" works for me, what exactly does "doesn't do much" mean?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I meant, sorry for being so imprecise.

Comment: You can't put preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" on a `<g>` element. The only way you're going to be able to do what you want is to calculate the aspect ratio yourself in javascript and apply an inverse transform to the text elements.

Comment: Or possibly experiment with two separate svg children in the `<div>` one with the text which is  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" and one with the rest of it which isn't.

Comment: @RobertLongson how would I keep the aspect ratio myself in JS? Could you outline that in an answer?

Comment: hook into resize events get the width and height and divide. Try it, if you get stuck I'll try to help.

Comment: @RobertLongson the style attributes height and width seem to not have any effect on text-tags. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73244/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-s-van-wickern).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Questions: How can you make the tag keep it's aspect ratio, while changing the aspect ratio of the svg?

You cannot.  If the text is part of the SVG it gets scaled with the SVG.  There is no way to make a part of the SVG exempt from the scaling.

Possible solutions:

(1) Remove the text from the SVG and position it on top. For example use a positioned `<div>` in your HTML or something.

(2) Use JS to calculate the aspect ratio of the SVG and apply an inverse scaling transform to the `<text>` element.

Comment: I added a div before it and wrote the positioning logic with js. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @S.vanWickern : can you please post your solution, which worked for you?

Comment: If you do it with a div outside the svg your case is quite simple because you just want the "OK" text in the center. You could position it with CSS, no JS needed.

Comment: I think I actually did find a way to do this in a clean pure SVG fashion. Feel free to check out my answer ;)

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question but I did find a way to do what is asked in pure SVG, no JS, and I've used it in prod without issues!

The trick is to define a parent `<svg>` element without a `viewBox` so that it takes the container's dimensions, and then define children `<svg>` elements for the different kind of `preserveAspectRatio` values that you want!

In the following snippet, I just took the SVG used in the question and put all the `<polygon>` apart in a `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">`.

```css
div {
  height: 112px;
  width: 200px;
}

div > svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

polygon {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <!-- SVG wrapper without viewBox to take parent's dimensions -->
  <svg>
  
    <!-- sub SVG that will be resized -->
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <g>
        <polygon points="0,0 100,0 65,35 35,35"></polygon>
        <text x="42" y="20"></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon points="100,0 100,100 65,65 65,35"></polygon>
        <text x="81" y="53"></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon points="0,100 35,65 65,65 100,100"></polygon>
        <text x="42" y="91"></text>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon points="0,0 35,35 35,65 0,100"></polygon>
        <text x="5" y="53"></text>
      </g>
    </svg>
    
    <!-- regular SVG elements that won't be resized -->
    <text id="ok_text" 
          x="50%" y="50%" 
          text-anchor="middle" 
          alignment-baseline="middle">
      OK
    </text>
    
  </svg>
</div>
```

PS: the end result can even be used as the src of a regular image `<img src="./my-weird-responsive-svg.svg" />` which makes this trick really robust!

Answer (score 0):

If you have javascript control on the current dimensions (like going fullscreen, for instance, or simply by checking what viewport size the user is using), you can add a simple class in a parent div outside the SVG.

Then, style the SVG text's font-size for both cases: when the parent div has such class (it tells you that your svg has scaled), and when the parent div hasn't such a class (i.e., the SVG is non-scaled). If this is your case, this simple solution works.

```
.svg_text {font-size: 12px;} /* normal non-scaled SVG */
.case_for_big_screen_thus_SVG_scaled .svg_text {font-size: 6px;} /* this parent class only is added when viewport dimensions make your SVG to be scaled */
```