# How to scale font-size based on width or height in logarithmic algorithm?

Tags: javascript

I have create a SVG chart dimension `900x500`, I want the font size to be scaled in `logarithmic` algorithm. When the chart is smaller It should scale normally, but after one limit it should scale `1px` in every `50px`. How can I do that ?

Here is a code i have tried.

```
function calculateFontSize(denominator, min, max) {
    var ratio = 0.038;
    var defaultSize = Math.round(denominator * multiplier);
    defaultSize = (defaultSize < min) ? min : (defaultSize > max) ? max : defaultSize;
}

var chartTitleSize = calculateFontSize(800, 14, 30);`
```

Comment: can you show what you tried so far? It is not a code writing service.

Comment: are you using SVG for text? or HTML ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve aspect ratio for SVG Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117299/preserve-aspect-ratio-for-svg-text)